# Objects not showing up in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, object

I haven´t had any issues with  this before but when i drag and drop any object into a `viewcontroller` it does not show up in the simulator but if i create it programmatically it works. I tried restarting Xcode, clearing Auto layout and uninstalled the app from the simulator without any success.

Is there some sort of global setting to i might have touched like not enabling Auto Layout? I also checked the view hierachy and saw that the object was not there, however when i took a look in preview it was there.

Comment: Did you set the constraints of the objects in the storyboard? By default they won't have any and don't display properly 9/10 times.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set the constraints correctly. To see if there is an underlying problem with the simulator, place an object in the upper left-hand corner of the View Controller, clean (Command - Shift - K) and run (Command - R) your project.